# Error when trying to use custom loss function in Pytorch binary classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to create a binary classification pytorch model using a custom loss function with the help of this [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html). The model works when using inbuilt loss functions such as `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` like in the tutorial. However, It gives an error when introducing the custom loss function.
Model code:

```
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
    since = time.time()

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs - 1}')
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # forward
                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                # statistics
                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

            epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

            print(f'{phase} Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f} Acc: {epoch_acc:.4f}')

            # deep copy the model
            if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                best_acc = epoch_acc
                best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

        print()

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print(f'Training complete in {time_elapsed // 60:.0f}m {time_elapsed % 60:.0f}s')
    print(f'Best val Acc: {best_acc:4f}')

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model

model_conv2 = torchvision.models.efficientnet_b7(weights = 'EfficientNet_B7_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1')
#model_conv = torchvision.models.efficientnet_b7(weights = 'EfficientNet_B7_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1')

for param in model_conv2.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Parameters of newly constructed modules have requires_grad=True by default
num_ftrs = model_conv2.classifier[1].in_features
model_conv2.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

model_conv2 = model_conv2.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Observe that only parameters of final layer are being optimized as
# opposed to before.
optimizer_conv = optim.SGD(model_conv2.classifier[1].parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_conv, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)
```

Also, what is the meaning of the output of the below code.

```
outputs = model(inputs)
_, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
loss = criterion(labels,preds)

outputs = tensor([[-0.1908,  0.4115],
                  [-1.0019, -0.1685],
                  [-1.1265, -0.3025],
                  [-0.5925, -0.6610],
                  [-0.4076, -0.4897],
                  [-0.6450, -0.2863],
                  [ 0.1632,  0.4944],
                  [-1.0743,  0.1003],
                  [ 0.6172,  0.5104],
                  [-0.2296, -0.0551],
                  [-1.3165,  0.3386],
                  [ 0.2705,  0.1200],
                  [-1.3767, -0.6496],
                  [-0.5603,  1.0609],
                  [-0.0109,  0.5767],
                  [-1.1081,  0.8886]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
```

From what I understand 16 rows represent the batch size. However, what do the value ranges mean? If its probabilities which probability represents which class (is the first value 0 class and second value class 1), Furthermore, why are there minus values and values more than one?

Please find the custom loss function below:

```
#Original Function
def pfbeta_fast(labels, predictions, beta):

    pTP = np.sum(labels * predictions)
    pFP = np.sum((1-labels) * predictions)
    num_positives = np.sum(labels)  #  = pTP+pFN

    pPrecision = pTP/(pTP+pFP)
    pRecall = pTP/num_positives

    beta_squared = beta**2

    if (pPrecision > 0 and pRecall > 0):
        pF1 = (1+beta_squared) * pPrecision * pRecall/(beta_squared*pPrecision + pRecall)
        return pF1
    else:
        return 0

#Adjusted function to fit model (by me)
def pfbeta_torch(predictions, labels , beta=1.3):
    #labels = torch.tensor(labels.clone().detach().requires_grad(True),dtype=torch.float64)
    #predictions = torch.tensor(predictions.clone().detach().requires_grad(True),dtype=torch.float64)
    predictions = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in predictions[:,1]] #Get second element and recode as 1 if value > than .5 else 0
    predictions = torch.tensor(predictions, requires_grad=True) #Loss function changed here
    pTP = torch.sum(labels * predictions)
    pFP = torch.sum((1-labels) * predictions)
    num_positives = torch.sum(labels)  #  = pTP+pFN

    pPrecision = pTP/(pTP+pFP)
    pRecall = pTP/num_positives

    beta_squared = beta**2

    if (pPrecision > 0 and pRecall > 0):
        pF1 = (1+beta_squared) * pPrecision * pRecall/(beta_squared*pPrecision + pRecall)
        return pF1
    else:
        return 0
```

Error message after plugging second function to model:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/1892088165.py in <module>
----> 1 model_conv = train_model(model_conv, criterion, optimizer_conv, exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=1)

/tmp/ipykernel_27/3271713126.py in train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs)
     33                     _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
     34                     print(outputs,labels)
---> 35                     loss = criterion(outputs,labels) #Changed here to criterion(labels,preds)
     36 
     37                     # backward + optimize only if in training phase

/tmp/ipykernel_27/3035900216.py in pfbeta_torch(predictions, labels, beta)
      3     #predictions = torch.tensor(predictions.clone().detach().requires_grad(True),dtype=torch.float64)
      4     predictions = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in predictions[:,1]] #Get second element and recode as 1 if value > than .5 else 0
----> 5     predictions = torch.tensor(predictions,requires_grad=True)
      6     pTP = torch.sum(labels * predictions)
      7     pFP = torch.sum((1-labels) * predictions)

RuntimeError: Only Tensors of floating point and complex dtype can require gradients
```

Additional code for understandability.

```
model_conv2 = torchvision.models.efficientnet_b7(weights = 'EfficientNet_B7_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1')
#model_conv = torchvision.models.efficientnet_b7(weights = 'EfficientNet_B7_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1')

for param in model_conv2.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

# Parameters of newly constructed modules have requires_grad=True by default
num_ftrs = model_conv2.classifier[1].in_features
model_conv2.classifier[1] = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

model_conv2 = model_conv2.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Observe that only parameters of final layer are being optimized as
# opposed to before.
optimizer_conv = optim.SGD(model_conv2.classifier[1].parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_conv, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

model_conv2 = train_model(model_conv2, criterion, optimizer_conv,
                         exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=25)
```

EDIT:
I changed my loss function as below;

```
def pfbeta_torch(predictions, labels, beta=1.3):
    #labels = torch.tensor(labels.clone().detach(), dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
    predictions = torch.tensor(predictions, dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
    pTP = torch.sum(labels * predictions)
    pFP = torch.sum((1 - labels) * predictions)
    num_positives = torch.sum(labels)  #  = pTP+pFN

    pPrecision = pTP / (pTP + pFP)
    pRecall = pTP / num_positives

    beta_squared = beta ** 2
    # x=0
    if (pPrecision > 0 and pRecall > 0):
        pF1 = (1 + beta_squared) * pPrecision * pRecall / (beta_squared * pPrecision + pRecall)
        return pF1
    else:
        return torch.tensor(0, dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
```

The inputs to the `loss` function are as below.

```
preds:  tensor([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
labels:  tensor([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Now I am sill getting a warning message this time;

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:3: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
```

Would anyone be able let me know whether I am correct in going about (second) custom function and what is the reason for the error please.

Thanks & Best Regards
AMJS

Comment: You cannot compute gradients over integer data, which is exactly what you do by thresholding predictions at 0.5.

Comment: Hi, @Dr.Snoopy I added some content. Please have a look. Thanks & Best Regards